# localStorage and onload JavaScript

Tags: javascript, local-storage, onload

I tried to make a function that displays an alert on the 1st page load `<body onload="alertbox()>"`, and its working on 2nd page load instead of 1st. What should i use instead of "onload" to make it work only on 1st load?

I'm beginner, sorry if it's a dumb question.

```
var alertboxStatus = localStorage.getItem("alertbox", alertboxStatus);
localStorage.setItem("alertbox", alertboxStatus)

function alertbox()
{
  if (alertboxStatus == "null" || alertboxStatus == "") 
  {
    alert("Alert!");
    alertboxStatus = "displayed";
    localStorage.setItem("alertbox", alertboxStatus);
  }
};
```

I also tried this:
But it's also working on second page load. Am i doing sth wrong with `locationStorage.setItem`?

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () 
{
  if (alertboxStatus == "null" || alertboxStatus == "") 
  {
    alert("alert");
    alertboxStatus = "displayed";
    localStorage.setItem("alertbox", alertboxStatus);
  }
}, false);
```

Changing "null" to null worked

Comment: try `null` instead of `"null"`

Comment: Could you please attach more code, and a reproducible example?

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve a numeric value in `localStorage` and assign it to a variable like this:

```
let nOfPageLoads = +( localStorage.getItem("nLoads") || 1 );
```

The `+` converts the retrieved value to a number. If `localStorage.nLoads` does not exist yet, `|| 1` sets `nOfPageLoads` to 1.

So, if the value of `nOfPageLoads` is 1, you know the page is visited for the first time. Do something if so (alerting or whatever).

After that, increase `nOfPageLoads` with 1 and set the value of `nLoads` in `localStorage` to the new value.

Here is [an example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-j8esb1?file=index.js) of this idea (in Stackblitz, because `localStorage` is sandboxed in SO-snippets).

Answer (score 0):

Try this, use null instead of "null"

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () 
{
  if (alertboxStatus == null || alertboxStatus == "") 
  {
    alert("alert");
    alertboxStatus = "displayed";
    localStorage.setItem("alertbox", alertboxStatus);
  }
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you check the status before working with it to avoid the issue with null and 'null'. Also it dosn't make a lot of sense to load the status and then save it again, since you don't change it here.

The null issue

```
'null' == null \\ = false
```

I think you can simplify it to this

```
// will always be null or 'displayed'
var alertboxStatus = localStorage.getItem("alertbox");

function alertbox()
{
  if (!alertboxStatus) 
  {
    alert("Alert!");
    alertboxStatus = "displayed";
    localStorage.setItem("alertbox", alertboxStatus);
  }
};
```